# Ordered list vertically on multiple columns in JS

Tags: javascript

Scope of this question is native Javascript only.

You have an ordered list of say 9 elements.

```
var elements = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I'];
```

You want to create this structure, having 2 columns. The last column may have 1 less row than the first because odd number of elements.

```
<div>
  <span>A</span><span>F</span><br>
  <span>B</span><span>G</span><br>
  <span>C</span><span>H</span><br>
  <span>D</span><span>I</span><br>
  <span>E</span>
</div>
```

I came up with this approach to start.

```
var container = document.createElement('div');
var elements = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I'];
var index = 0;
var midpoint = Math.ceil(elements.length / 2);
var line = "";

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  if (i == 0) {
    index = 0
  }
  else if (i % 2 == 1) {
    index = midpoint + Math.floor(i / 2);
  }
  else if (i > 0)  {
    index = i - i / 2;
  }

  var el = document.createElement('span');
  el.innerText = elements[index];
  container.appendChild(el);
  if (i > 0 && i % 2 == 1) {
    container.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
  }
}
```

But now I am looking for a more generic function, so I can just pass to the function the number of columns.

Do you know an implementation?

Comment: is it mandatory that `E` item should be the last `<span>`, but not `I` item?

Comment: yes ```I``` being the last element, it should be in the last span of last column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could specify the number of cols and use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) with taking the length divided by the cols for the row count. The result is an array with the wanted cols and rows.

This array is iterated for the wanted output.

```js
var array = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I'],
    cols = 3,
    target = document.body;

array
    .reduce(function (r, a, i, aa) {
        var index = i % Math.ceil(aa.length / cols);
        r[index] = r[index] || [];
        r[index].push(a);
        return r;
    }, [])
    .forEach(function (a) {
        a.forEach(function (b) {
            var span = document.createElement('span');
            span.appendChild(document.createTextNode(b));
            target.appendChild(span);
        });
        target.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
    });
```

Comment: trying to understand ```r[i % l] = r[i % l] || [];```

Comment: that line assigns an array if the value of `r[i % l]` is falsey. basically if the element is not an array, assign an array.